# How do i Update a row with PDO?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, pdo

How do I turn this code into a code that works with PDO?

```
if($_POST['name']=='home_title'){
$id=$_POST['pk'];
$home_title=$_POST['value'];
$result=mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM sw_configuration WHERE id=$id") or die(mysql_error());
$count= mysql_fetch_row($result);
if($count[0]==0){
   mysql_query("INSERT INTO sw_configuration(id,home_title) VALUES('".$id."','".$home_title."')") or die(mysql_error()); 
}else{
   mysql_query("UPDATE sw_configuration SET home_title='".$home_title."' WHERE id=$id") or die(mysql_error()); 
  }
}
```

Comment: have you tried something yet?

Comment: You should consider accepting some answers to your questions. You haven't accepted a single answer yet out of the 9 questions you have asked. Both you and the person who answered gain reputation plus it shows future visitors what worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

Simply using PDO is **not enough** to make your script secure from SQL injection attacks. You still need to make sure **all** of your user-supplied variables are either properly [quoted](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.quote.php) or better yet, use prepared statements with bound parameters, which is the preferred way. If you don't do this, there is no difference security-wise between using PDO and the regular `mysql_*` functions. Here is an example of how you can do it:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO sw_configuration(id,home_title) 
    VALUES(:id,:home_title)");
$stmt->bindValue(':id', $id);
$stmt->bindValue(':home_title', $home_title);
$stmt->execute();
```

Or if you need to select a value:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM sw_configuration WHERE id = :id");
$stmt->bindValue(':id', $id);
$stmt->execute();

$count = $stmt->fetchColumn();
```